If $f$ is regular on a subvariety $X$ of $Y$, then $f$ extends to a regular function on $Y$
Let $k$ be algebraically closed, if it matters. I am reading Algebraic Varieties by Kempf and on page 59 it asserts that if $X\subset Y$ is a closed subvariety of a variety, then the natural homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_Y\to\mathcal{O}_X$ is surjective. I cannot find a source for it.
Here is my proof:
Consider the case when $X$ and $Y$ are projective. Let $f$ be regular on $X$. Let $f_i=p_i/q_i$ for $i\in I$ be the representatives on open set $U_i$. If $\bigcap_I V(q_i)$ is empty, then $f$ extends to the whole space. Otherwise $X$ and $\bigcap_I V(q_i)$ are closed non-empty projective varieties, therefore intersect, contradiction.
Is there a simpler way? And presumably this extends to any closed immersion?

That is strange, as surjectivity is part of the definition of a closed immersion.

@CraniumClamp This was my own addition. In a comment on this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/589986/1287132 , someone said a closed immersion is "a fancy word for the inclusion of a closed subvariety", which seems to not be the whole story.

When you write $ \mathcal{O}_Y $ etc, do you mean the sheaf? The definition of a closed immersion (for me, at least) requires surjectivity of sheaves, but not global sections necessarily.

Your proposed proof has some issues. First, if $X$ and $Y$ are projective, there are no regular functions on $X$ or $Y$ other than constants. Second, it is not true that any two closed subvarieties of a projective variety intersect. As CraniumClamp suggests, you should be trying to prove a statement about the sheaf of regular functions rather than global regular functions on a fixed variety.
